# Check if Dictionary Values exist in a another Dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to compare values from 2 Dictionaries in Python.  I want to know if a value from one Dictionary exists anywhere in another Dictionary.  Here is what i have so far.  If it exists I want to return True, else False.

The code I have is close, but not working right.
I'm using VS2012 with Python Plugin

I'm passing both Dictionary items into the functions.

```
def NameExists(best_guess, line):
    return all (line in best_guess.values() #Getting Generator Exit Error here on values
        for value in line['full name'])
```

Also, I want to see if there are duplicates within best_guess itself.

```
def CheckDuplicates(best_guess, line):   
    if len(set(best_guess.values())) != len(best_guess):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As error is about generator exit, I guess you use python 3.x. So `best_guess.values()` is a generator, which exhaust for the first `value in line['full name']` for which a match will not be found.

Also, I guess `all` usage is incorrect, if you look for **any** value to exist (not sure, from which one dictinary though).

You can use something like follows, providing `line` is the second dictionary:

```
def NameExists(best_guess, line):
    vals = set(best_guess.values())
    return bool(set(line.values()).intersection(vals))
```

Comment: I'm getting an attribute error.  The ['full name'] is a value from the line dictionary, and I want to see if any of those value items match any other items within the whole best_guess Dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax in `NameExists` seems wrong, you aren't using the `value` and `best_guess.values()` is returning an iterator, so `in` will only work once, unless we convert it to a list or a set (you are using Python 3.x, aren't you?). I believe this is what you meant:

```
def NameExists(best_guess, line):
    vals = set(best_guess.values())
    return all(value in vals for value in line['full name'])
```

And the `CheckDuplicates` function can be written in a shorter way like this:

```
def CheckDuplicates(best_guess, line):
    return len(set(best_guess.values())) != len(best_guess)
```

Comment: It seems you forgot len for first set in  `CheckDuplicates`

Comment: Yes, I'm using Python 3.3.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez "in won't work" is not correct, `in` **will** work for a generator, but will consume it eventually

Comment: @alko, yes, still getting GeneratorExit for some reason.

Comment: @Airborne the nature of line['full name'] is ambiguous. see my answer for an approach in this direction